# Read a file and add it to a textbox : string conversion issue

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage, stdstring

I use:

```
std::ifstream t("myfile.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) str);
```

to read the content of `myfile.txt` into a textbox created with:

```
HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, L"EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, ...)
```

**How to solve this error?** :

```
main.cpp(34) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'LPARAM' 
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPARAM` is defined as: `typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM`

So basically it expects a pointer to some data that is passed through the message.
Then the receiver can interpret it according to message type.

If you want to pass a string, you should pass its underlying `c_str()`.
And of course make sure that string is valid until the message arrives:

```
SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) str.c_str());
```

Comment: It nearly works, but `myfile.txt` contains `Bonjour`, then this is added in the textbox : `潂橮畯r`... Is there a Unicode problem?   (I have `#ifndef UNICODE / #define UNICODE / #endif `  on top of my code

Comment: Use `WM_SETTEXTA` as a quick fix.

Comment: @JonathanPotter `error C2065: 'WM_SETTEXTA' : undeclared identifier`  but `SendMessageA(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, ...)` works. 
Unicode, Wchar, etc. are like magic...

Comment: @Basj: Heh, you're right - there's no such thing. Oops :) If your application is compiled for Unicode you'll need to convert the string to a wide string using `MultiByteToWideChar` before you can send it to the window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't see exactly what you mean, can you provide an answer with the code?

Comment: @Basj: Even easier: use `SetWindowTextA` instead of sending `WM_SETTEXT` manually. This will convert your string automatically (it's what I was actually thinking of when I suggested `WM_SETTEXTA` but I'd forgotten that the thunk only exists for the function, not as a message).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand documentation of WM_SETTEXT lparam should be

> A pointer to a null-terminated string that is the window text.

which means c style string, a char* variable. You could try pass str.c_str() a lParam.